# Segmentation fault when not specifying input file on command line

Tags: c, file, stdin

I am writing a program that reads from a file passed as an arguement, or reads from stdin if no arguements are given.
The code runs fine with a file passed, but I get a seg fault when no file is passed.
I basically call fopen on argv[1] if a file was given, but if no file was given I call:

```c
f = fopen("stdin", "r");
```

Is this the correct syntax for opening stdin as a file?

Comment: You don't need to manually open `stdin`, the operating system takes care of that. So you just simply use `stdin`.

Comment: I'm trying to make the program work with f whether it is a txt file or stdin so I have to make f point to stdin if no file arg was passed.

Comment: I see what you mean now I don't need to open stdin manually I can just set f = stdin, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you start a program, the `main()` function is not the first thing that
get's called, quite a few things happen before the `main()` function is
called. One of those things is to open `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`. In
general you don't need to worry about the details how the OS does that, you
just can relay that when `main()` is executed, these streams are open and you
can use them.

So in your case, you can do this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int args, char **argv) {
    FILE *fp;

    if(args == 1) {
        fp = stdin;
    } else {
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        if(fp == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open %s for writing\n", argv[1]);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // do your read operations on fp

    if(fp != stdin) {
        fclose(fp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So when you call the program without arguments, `stdin` is used, otherwise a
file is used.

The reason why your code crashes is because

```c
f = fopen("stdin", "r");
```

tries to open a file literally called `stdin`, which you most probably don't
have. `fopen` will return `NULL` and you probably don't check for that. If you
try to use a function that expects a `FILE*` pointer but pass `NULL`, then
you'll most likely will get a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

USE f = stdin;
NOT f = fopen("stdin", "r");